# Getting notification in console but not in notification center

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

Coding iOS app in react-native (0.35.0) and using iPad mini (9.3.5) as a test device. Already made Android app with successfully implementing react-native-fcm module for notifications.

Problem I'm facing now in iOS development is that I do receive notification while app is in background but I do not get it in notif center (I can just catch it in console). I have no idea why is it happening.

This is the module I'm using [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) . I've followed all the instructions in Cocoapods and in manual integration but I can't make it work. I get no errors what so ever. Tried by directly pushing app to device trough xCode and by archiving it (thought that it might be bundling problem).

Any help would be highly appreciated (even though if someone hasn't worked in react-native but ran into this problem in for example swift). If needed I can provide more information.

Best regards,
Bepo.

**EDIT:**

I'm sending this JSON:

```
{
 "notification" : {
    "body" : "Notif body",
    "title" : "notif",
    "icon" : "myicon",
    "sound" : "default",
    "vibrate": "default",
    "extra" : "Some extra I need"
 },
 "data" :{
    "redirectUrl" : "Url that I need to redirect person after it clicks on notif"
 },
"to" : "token that I've gotten",
"content_available": true,
"priority" : "high",
"show_in_foreground": true
}
```

with headers:

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key= my Api key on firebase
```

FCM response:

```
{
 "multicast_id": ***************45844,
 "success": 1,
 "failure": 0,
 "canonical_ids": 0,
 "results": [
    {
      "message_id": "0:********************a1027b"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notification i'm catching in console:

```
{ notification: 
{ title: 'notif',
sound: 'default',
vibrate: 'default',
icon: 'myicon',
extra: 'Some extra I need',
sound2: 'default',
e: '1',
body: 'Notif body' },
redirectUrl: 'Url that I need to redirect person after it clicks on notif',
collapse_key: 'My app id',
opened_from_tray: 0,
from: '*********' }
```

Comment: Please show me your APS format, In other words notification format you got from FCM.

Comment: Check your payload msg if in payload there are no msg text available then popup will not come in notification center but you can check it by consol

Comment: I've edited my post with json examples I'm sending and receiving from firebase

Comment: Is Push Notificaiton ON in project target->capabilities ??

Comment: Yes I've enabled push notification, keychain sharing and background modes (remote notifications).

Comment: Still no luck on my side. Still trying to make it work. Have no clue why is it happening.